# Sync google cloud storage with CDN to products images

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-images, cdn, external-images

I have a GCS folder with all my products images and now I've configured a CDN (always with Google) linked to this source. I would use these images for my Magento 2 store, specifically, I 'd like to be able to link each product to image into my google storage bucket.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

create product in magento with images, then you sync media base folder to GCS.

```
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-gsutil
```

or you can use special extension that automates it for you:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=google+cloud+storage+magento+2
```

create `CNAME` for your bucket, and then in magento 2 admin settings you change base url for media and static files to point to your `CNAME` end name.

```
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/request-endpoints
```

so your final url for example will be like:

```
https://CNAME_TO_GCS/media/catalog/product/cache/207e232def205098cf3c8a3/i/m/image.jpg
```